# Laravel 5 get APP_DEBUG environment variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

On Laravel 5, on a blade template I want to `@yield` a part of code only if the environment variable APP_DEBUG is set to true. The code on the blade template is:

```
@if(env('APP_DEBUG') == 1)
    @yield('debugcontrols')
@endif
```

However no matter if I set `APP_DEBUG=false` on my .env the line `env('APP_DEBUG')` will always retrieve 1 while all other environment variables will retrieve its correct value.

**How do I get the APP_DEBUG environment variable?**

Note that all other environment variables print correctly, for example with,

```
APP_DEBUG=false
DB_HOST=localhost
```

The code,

```
{{ env('DB_HOST') }}
{{ env('APP_DEBUG') }}
{{ Config::get('app.debug') }}
```

will render,

```
localhost 1 1
```

Comment: Did you have any other setting to allow Blade to echo an env variable? When I try `{{ env('APP_DEBUG') }}` I get nothing..

Comment: Same thing for me @greener. But I managed to pull something out in my blade view with. `{{ config('app.name') }}` will return APP_NAME from my .env file. Of course when ever you make changes to .env file, be sure to run `php artisan config:cache` to let you application know to clean the config cache. My version of laravel 5.3.30.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I solved it, I can't believe it was so simple... The function `env()` does not gets the values from the .env file when called. Apparently the .env variables are stored somewhere so it is needed to close and start again the server with `php artisan serve`.

Comment: In memory, I would imagine.